# Nested TabNavigator inside StackNavigator: controlling the header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a setup much like this:

```
let Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    screen1: Screen1,
    screen2: Screen2
})

let Stack = createStackNavigator({
    tabs: Tabs
    otherScreen: OtherScreen
})
```

The stack navigator has a header, and that's fine. What I want is to get different header icons depending on what tab I'm currently on.

I'm using the following versions:

```
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "~0.55.2",
"react-navigation": "^2.2.5"
```

I've considered switching up my setup so that each tab screen has its own `StackNavigator` but I like having the sliding animation when switching tabs and I don't want the header icons to slide along. The header bar should remain static but simply show different icons depending on the current tab.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use like this below, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

```
//Screen1 Stack.

const Screen1 = createStackNavigator ({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null //Need to set header as null.
        }
    }
});

//Screen2 Stack

const Screen2 = createStackNavigator ({
    Profile: {
        screen: Profile,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null  //Need to set header as null.
        }
    }
});


let Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Screen1:{
      screen: Screen1 //Calling Screen1 Stack.
    },
    Screen2:{
      screen: Screen2 //Calling Screen2 Stack.
    }
},{ tabBarPosition: 'bottom' }) //this will set the TabBar at Bottom of your screen.

let Stack = createStackNavigator({
    tabs:{
      screen: Tabs, //You can add the NavigationOption here with navigation as parameter using destructuring.
      navigationOptions: ({navigation})=>{
       //title: (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index])["routeName"]  
       //this will fetch the routeName of Tabs in TabNavigation. If you set the routename of the TabNavigation as your Header. 

       //use the following title property,this will fetch the current stack's routeName which will be set as your header in the TabBar.

        //title: (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routes"])[(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["index"])].routeName

       //you can use switch case,on matching the route name you can set title of the header that you want and also header left and right icons similarly.

        switch ((navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routes"])[(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["index"])].routeName) {
            case "Screen1":
                return {
                    title: "Home", 
                    headerLeft: (<Button
                        onPress={()=> alert("hi")}
                        title="Back"
                        color="#841584"
                        accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                    /> ),
                    headerRight: <Button title= "Right"/>
                }
            case "Screen2":
                return { 
                    title: "Profile",
                    headerLeft: (<Button
                        onPress={()=> alert("hi")}
                        title="Back"
                        color="#841584"
                        accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                    /> ),
                    headerRight: <Button title= "Right"/>
                }
            default:
                return { title: (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routes"])[(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["index"])].routeName }
        }
      }
    },
    otherScreen:{
      screen: OtherScreen
    }
})
```

//navigationOptions

```
  navigationOptions: ({navigation})=>{
   //title: (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index])["routeName"]  
   //this will fetch the routeName of Tabs in TabNavigation. If you set the routename of the TabNavigation as your Header. 

   //use the following title property,this will fetch the current stack's routeName which will be set as your header in the TabBar.

    //title: (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routes"])[(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["index"])].routeName

    switch ((navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routes"])[(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["index"])].routeName) {
        case "Screen1":
            return {
                title: "Home", 
                headerLeft: (<Button
                    onPress={()=> alert("hi")} //Here you can able to set the back behaviour.
                    title="Back"
                    color="#841584"
                    accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                /> ),
                headerRight: <Button title= "Right"/>
            }
        case "Screen2":
            return { 
                title: "Profile",
                headerLeft: (<Button
                    onPress={()=> alert("hi")} 
                    title="Back"
                    color="#841584"
                    accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                /> ),
                headerRight: <Button title= "Right"/>
            }
        default:
            return { title: (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routes"])[(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["index"])].routeName }
    }
  }
```

//alert(navigation.state)

```
{

    "routes":[
        {
            "key":"Screen1",
            "routeName":"Screen1",
            "routes":[
                {
                    "key":"Home",
                    "routeName":"Home",
                }
            ],
            "index":0,
            "isTransitioning":false,
            "key":"id-1530276062643-0"
        },
        {
            "key":"Screen2",
            "routeName":"Screen2",
            "routes":[
                {
                    "key":"Profile",
                    "routeName":"Profile",
                }
            ],
            "index":0,
            "isTransitioning":false,
            "key":"id-1530276062643-0"
        }
    ],
    "index":0,
    "isTransitioning":false,
    "routeName":"tabs",
    "key":"id-1530276062643-0"

}
```

//(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index])["routeName"]
  //(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routes"])[(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["index"])].routeName

```
this will give the current route name of the tab inside StackNavigation.
```

The above code will set the title in root stack header where the TabBar resides as first route,so we are setting the header as null for the individual stack in TabBar. By using this way will provide Animation while switching the screens in TabBar since header will remain static.

you can find the working copy here https://www.dropbox.com/s/jca6ssn9zkzh9kn/Archive.zip?dl=0

Download this and Execute the following.

1. > npm install //to get dependencies
2. > react-native upgrade //to get android and ios folder
3. > react-native link //to link dependencies and libraries
4. > react-native run-ios (or) react-native run-android

   you can use the above, Let me know if any.

Comment: @Anthony De Smet, I have updated my answer kindly check it and let me know if this fix yours.

Comment: Although this works, you can't change the header title to anything else than the routeName, can you? e.g. "Screen2" title will always be "Screen2", or can you somehow set it to be: "Screen title for sub item XXX"?

Comment: @Chris, I have updated my answer as per your requirement. You can achieve it, by using switch case in navigationOptions which matches our routeName to set the title, headerLeft, headerRight etc. By this way we can able to set the title irrespective of routeName.

Comment: @dhivyas I also got question about nested tabs right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888800/react-native-expo-how-to-make-nested-tab do you think we can solve with similar solution?

Comment: can you check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999290/how-to-navigate-from-creatematerialtoptabnavigatorto-other-screen-react-naviga 
@dhivyas

Comment: How can I do that with react-natigation 5?

Comment: There is a good example in official document here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve the desired behavior with the current navigation stack configuration of yours. You might need to change couple of things and combine couple of properties but it is fairly simple when you get yor head around it.

I try to explain it with a small example.

Consider having below navigators;

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    screen1: Tab1,
    screen2: Tab2
})

const Stack = createStackNavigator({
    tabs: {
      screen: TabsPage,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
        return { title: (navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.title ? navigation.state.params.title : 'No Title' ) }
      }
    },
    otherScreen: Page
})
```

As you can see I am setting the title parameter from the navigation state. To be ale to set the param for that navigator, we are going to get help from [`screenProps`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#using-params-in-the-title) property;

```
class TabsPage extends Component {
  onTabsChange = (title) => {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ title })
  }
  render() {
    return(<Tabs screenProps={{ onTabsChange: this.onTabsChange }} />)
  }
}
```

I created a wrapper component for tab navigator and passed down a function which is setting the title parameter.

For the last part we need to know how and when to use that function we passed down. For that we are going to use [`addListener`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) navigation prop

```
class Tab1 extends React.Component {
  setTitle = () => {
    this.props.screenProps.onTabsChange('Title from Tab 1')
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.setTitle)
  }
  render() {
    return <View><Text>{'Tab1'}</Text></View>
  }
}
```

When our tab focused the passed function will run and then set the title for that tab. You can use this process for setting different buttons or icons for the header. You can find the working snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/SJI_N_zGm).

Comment: This is a better solution indeed but how do you navigate to "otherScreen"? this.props.navigation.navigate('Page'); doesn't work from within Tab1 or Tab2

Comment: can you check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999290/how-to-navigate-from-creatematerialtoptabnavigatorto-other-screen-react-naviga @bennygenel

Answer (score 1):

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    FilterScreen: createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
        Tab1: {screen:Tab1Screen},
        Tab2: {screen: Tab2Screen},
    }),
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);


render() {
    return <RootStack/>;
}
```

Comment: can you check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999290/how-to-navigate-from-creatematerialtoptabnavigatorto-other-screen-react-naviga @MahdiBashirpour

Answer (score 0):

In AppNavigation.js //or where you have defined your routes.

```js
let Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    screen1: Screen1,
    screen2: Screen2
})

let Stack = createStackNavigator({
    tabs: Tabs
    otherScreen: OtherScreen
},{
    headerMode:"float", //Render a single header that stays at the top and animates as screens are changed. This is a common pattern on iOS.
    headerTransitionPreset:"fade-in-place" //this will give a slight transition when header icon change.
  }
)
```

In Screen1.js

```js
class Screen1 extends Component {
 
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

    return {
      ...
      headerLeft: <HeaderLeftImage navigation={navigation} image={"Image_For_Screen1"}/>,
      ...
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

NOTE: You can add title, headersStyle,headerRight in same way read this link [header configuration](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigationoptions-for-screens-inside-of-the-navigator) for more detail

In Screen2.js do similar to Screen1

```js
class Screen2 extends Component {
 
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

    return {
      ...
      headerLeft: <HeaderLeftImage navigation={navigation} image={"Image_For_Screen2"}/>,
      ...
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Header.js

```js
export const HeaderLeftImage = (props) => (
    <View style={{
       'add styles'
    }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {"Add action here" }}>
            <Image source={props.image} resizeMethod='resize' style={{ height: 30, width: 90, resizeMode: 'contain' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)
```

Hope this helps, if you have any doubt regarding the code feel free to ask.

Comment: can you check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999290/how-to-navigate-from-creatematerialtoptabnavigatorto-other-screen-react-naviga @RajatGupta

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react navigation <2 i.e ~1.5.* You can set it like this.

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    Tab1:{
         screen: Tab1,
         navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
            return { title: "Tab 1 Heading", tabBarLabel:"Tab 1 "}
    },
    }
    Tab2:{
       screen: Tab2
       navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
         return { title: "Tab 2 Heading", tabBarLabel:"Tab 2 "}
    }
    }
})

const Stack = StackNavigator({
    tabs: {
      screen: Tabs
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
        return { title: "Stack"}
      }
    },
    otherScreen: Page
})
```

I'm not sure why did they remove this feature, when you try the same it won't work on the latest react-navigation. Now title object key is used for fallback it seems.

This may be helpful some users. If you wish you can try downgrading also.

I have the Upgraded the React Navigation for my project I think this way will be useful to someone

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
     Tab1:{
        screen: Tab1,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
           return { tabBarLabel:"Tab 1 "}
        }},
     Tab2:{
        screen: Tab2
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
           return { tabBarLabel:"Tab 2 "}
        }}
});
Tabs.navigationOptions = ({navigation})=>{
    const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]; //This gives current route
    switch(routeName){
         case "Tab1":
           headerTitle="Tab 1";
           break;
         case "Tab1":
           headerTitle="Tab 1";
           break;
    }

 return {
   headerTitle: headerTitle
}
}
```

Comment: can you check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999290/how-to-navigate-from-creatematerialtoptabnavigatorto-other-screen-react-naviga @AshwinMothilal

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use property `headerShown: false`. I have created a working example of `react-navigation` version: `5.x.x`, nesting different navigators: `stack`, `drawer` & `bottom-tabs`.

*Here's the link to github:*
https://github.com/mvpbuddy/react-native-nested-navigators/

*For a more detailed overview, you can checkout my blog:*
https://mvpbuddy.io/blog/detail/how-to-build-an-app-with-nested-stack-drawer-bottom-tab-navigators